# Trouble finding a function to convert float into a comma seperated thousands ASP CLASSIC

Tags: asp-classic, format

Having trouble finding a function to convert float into a comma seperated thousands in ASP CLASSIC

it needs to format a variety of numbers:

```
0.01
-.1
100000.45
993000
```

they should end up like:

```
 0.01
-0.1
100,000.45
993,000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would `FormatNumber(yournumber, 2)` work for you?

The thousands separator is a part of how your data is displayed. This is called Globalization and is configured by `Response.LCID` or `Session.LCID` (for all responses).

More info about the localeID and how to set it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525091(v=vs.90).aspx

I suspect an english or american locale sets the thousands separator with a comma.

**EDIT**

If you want more information on the parameters of `FormatNumber`, you can find them at the [W3Schools FormatNumber](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_formatnumber.asp) reference.

Comment: I see how this formats the numbers precision. I am figuring some stuff out on if I really need to do this comma thing... thank you so much. I assume this must be the correct answer, everything's there :)

Comment: You're welcome :) If you have more questions, feel free to ask them